# how to test sns APNS push notifications to a single device

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

How can I verify my AWS SNS credentials for APNS in production? I needed to update the credentials (public/private key) because the original certificate is expiring, now I want to test sending a push notification to a single device so that I don't spam every user with a test push notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to determine the SNS ARN for the specific device you want to send a push notification to, usually this can be done by inspecting the network traffic of the app with [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). Look for a request to `sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and find the EndpointArn attribute in the request that contains a guid after your SNS Application Name:

[image: SNS EndpointArn value]

Then you can trigger the push notification using the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html) command below, replacing the `target-arn` option with the EndpointArn determined from the previous step.

```
aws sns publish --target-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<aws account id>:endpoint/APNS/<sns application name>/<device guid>" --message "test"
```

Other tips:

- Push notifications only work with apps downloaded via the App Store (including Test Flight), but not with apps installed via XCode.
- Be sure to include the device GUID after the application name to target a single device only in the `target-arn` argument.